# Media Query isn't working on live server but it does work on local

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, media-queries

So, this is my issue. I think i've tried all the fixes I've seen on similar topics, but nothing seems to work and I don't understand why. It's my first deployment of a website aswell. Also my first attempt at making a mobile first site, with the idea of making it look like an app.

https://styleplace.pt

On the "Sobre nós" section of the page, I have an h2 and 2 p, and **I want to show only one of the p's on mobile and everything in desktop**. But on the deployed page, it doesn't work. Warning: the code is a little more rought in this part of the site because of all the fixes i've been trying to implement.

I'm leaving here a little bit more code than exactly the 3 elements in question, since I don't know if the parent elements can have something to do with it or not ( im really out of ideas on this one).

HTML

```css
.sobreTexto {
    border-radius: 3rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    width: 80%;
    height: 23vh;
    background: #111;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 1.2rem 1.2rem 1.2rem 1.2rem;
    box-shadow: -0.5rem 0.5rem 1rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.sobreSoDesktopH2 {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    display: none;
}

.sobreSempre {
    width: 63%;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.sobreSoDesktop {
    width: 63%;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    display: none;
}

.sobreEmBaixo {
    height: 33vh;
}

.sobrePic {
    width: 35vw;
    height: 35vh;
    z-index: 20;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: -0.5rem 0.5rem 1rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0.5rem 0px 1rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 4rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6vw;
    top: calc(11.5vh - 17.0vh);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {

  .sobreSoDesktop {
      display: block;
  }

  .sobreSoDesktopH2 {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sobre">
    <div class="caption2">
        <p>Sobre nós</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sobreEmBaixo">
        <div class="flexContainer2">
            <div class="sobreTexto">
                <h2 class="sobreSoDesktopH2">Davi Jonatas:</h2>
                <p class="sobreSempre">
                    Trabalhei em uma barbearia quando cheguei a Portugal, há 3 anos atrás e venho  buscando evoluir profissionalmente, trazer <strong>conforto</strong> e <strong>qualidade</strong> nos nossos serviços e trazer também aos nossos clientes o melhor atendimento.
                </p>
                <p class="sobreSoDesktop">Estamos sempre nos atualizando para chegar na nossa melhor versão e nossa motivação vem da satisfação dos nossos clientes e amigos.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sobrePic">
                <img 
                srcset="
                imgs/Fotos/2juntos.jpeg 1125w,
                imgs/Fotos/2juntos_230x230.png 230w,
                imgs/Fotos/2juntos_394x400.png 394w
                "
                src="imgs/Fotos/2juntos.jpeg"
                alt="Davi e Gedeão Jonatas, barbeiros juntos">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If someone could help me, that would be amazing. Thank you

Comment: Here it seems to work correctly. Did you close correctly your media-query because in code given before I edited you did not ? You forgot `}` and also set media query like: `@media screen and (min-width: 1025px)`

Comment: Thanks for the edit !
Yes, the media query is closed. Have you seen the page i've linked to ? That's the deployed site. Does it work there for you ?

Comment: Checking it. It is weird. Because your block just appear, If I search directly in html. It seems to be very far in the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS you gave us works. It's just that you don't actually have that CSS on your website.

**How can I see that?**

`Inspect Element > Sources > CSS > *style.css`

Once you're in the file, I just added this code at the bottom, and it worked :^)

```css
.sobreSoDesktop{
    display:none;
}
@media (min-width: 1025px) {

  .sobreSoDesktop {
      display: block;
  }

  .sobreSoDesktopH2 {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

[image: Proof of concept]

**This is all the CSS I can find in related to any `@media` query**

```css
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    .cardEquipa {
        width: 25vw;
    }
    .sobrePic img {
        object-position: 0rem -1rem;
    }
    .linearBackground {
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .textoLocalizacao {
        padding-left: 10vw;
    }
    .mapa {
        padding-left: 40vw;
    }
    .servicinho {
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 20vw;
        height: 20vh;
    }
    .imagemServicinho {
        height: 10vh;
        width: 10vh;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }
    .imagemServicinho img {
        width: 10vh;
        height: 10vh;
    }
    .servicinhoIgual {
        display: block;
    }
    .servicinhoPreco {
        padding-right: 1rem;
    }
    .redesSociais {
        width: 20%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I would highly suggest removing the scroll transition. It scrolls too far on the page, and I'm afraid it might lose you potential customers.

Comment: Thanks so much Audun ! I'm gonna try to see what happened and I'll be back in a minute.

About the scroll transition, I think that's a problem in the height of elements I still didn't fixed, but thank you a lot !

Comment: I don't know what's happening, it doesn't reload the new files. Even if I delete the css file, the page keeps having style

Comment: Finally did it. Just added "?v=1.02" to the link rel stylesheet and it started reloading the changes I made.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1.02">

It's working. Thank you so much.